# Fill empty row when have one id record in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon, i want to ask about MySql query.

I have the initial data as pict below.
[initial datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad7Ai.png)

I want to calculate the number of hours difference by displaying several data columns with the MySql query below.

```
SELECT id AS id,name AS Name,MIN(received_date) as tap_in,MAX(received_date) as tap_out,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(received_date),MAX(received_date)) AS work_hours from tb_gate_log where date(received_date) ='2023-06-06' group by global_id;
```

and it works like pict below.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3IX5.png)

however, there are cases such as there is only one data with status only "OUT" or "IN" for one id. I want the result like pict below when have status "Out" or "IN" only in one id.[result i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLn9.png)

Thank You,
Regards.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in particular the section DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and let me know if the problem still exists:

```
SELECT id AS id,name AS Name,IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(received_date),MAX(received_date))>0, MIN(received_date),'') as tap_in,MAX(received_date) as tap_out,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,MIN(received_date),MAX(received_date)) AS work_hours from tb_gate_log where date(received_date) ='2023-06-06' group by global_id;
```